# How to add Realm's Classpath to Gradle's Javadoc Classpath Variable

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, realm, javadoc

I am trying to use Gradle to generate a Javadoc for my Android Library Project. Right now I have included Android's Source Classpath to Gradle's Classpath variable that Gradle uses to generate the Javadoc.

```
task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = reporting.file("api-docs")
}
```

But when I run the task it gives an error that it cannot find the symbol `@Ignore` which is an annotation provided by Realm.

```
symbol:   class Ignore
location: class TreatmentPlan    
/Documents/Repo/calendar_android/calendar/src/main/java/com/company/calendar/Calendar.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    @Ignore
     ^
```

I am assuming that since I have not included Realm's Classpath inside my Gradle task, that gradle doesn't know how to generate a javadoc for the annotation.

How can I include Realm's classpath in my gradle task?

Comment: You could also use the `exclude` function to discard Realm classes from your documentation.